# httponly cookie in react and node js based application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt, httponly

I have one website whose **frontend** is **React** with link **myaapplication.com** and backend  api is node Js with link **api.myapplication.com**. I am using JWT for authentication.  I am sending token as JSON response.

**My Issue is**

**I don't want to store these cookie in local storage or client side cookie.**

*How can i secure this ??*

**WHAT I tried**

- I passed token in res.cookie with httponly flag.
- Using Proxy to use httponly cookie in my react app using code `{ ... "proxy": "http://localhost:3001" }`, it was working fine

**But** As per document it will work only in development not in production .

**Any way to make it secure in production ??**

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In production you'll be deploying your builded app. Where your front-end will be served as static from your back-end.